# How can you configure the default language for site collections?

Tags: sharepoint-on-prem, language

I know you can set the default language when you create a site collection using powershell. However, if you don't specify this, it uses a default value. Where is this default value set?

I can't see anything in the SharePoint installation process for setting this? We are in Australia, but a lot of site collections are created with EN-US as the language. This has the effect of setting the locale settings to English - United States, which uses the "wrong" date format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Default language is the language you installed the sharepoint server. I.e. If you base installation of sharepoint server is en-us than this will be default language value for all operations and for additional language support you have to install the language packs of that language.

Comment: Do you mean the installation app? Does that mean the installation app is available for for all of the different languages? There is no option to choose a language during the installation process.

Comment: I mean 1st time when you install the SharePoint the bits you used. If you go to the Download page, you will see different langugae Option, select the language in which you want to install the SharePoint. I am little doubted about En-AU if that is avaiable. following languages avaiable for SharePoint 2013 Languages

Arabic, Chinese (Simplified), Chinese (Traditional), Dutch, English, French, German, Hebrew, Italian, Japanese, Korean, Portuguese (Brazil), Russian, Spanish

Comment: I also can't find an en-au installation file. So this implies there is no way to set the default language for new site collections to anything but en-us if you are using the English language. The main hassle with this is that the regional settings will be wrong for site collections created through Central Admin. Frustrating.

Comment: Yes, you are right. That is one kind of limitations.